# Object [Object array] or [Object object] has no method 'then'

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

Felt like sharing this because it has bugged me a few times and I keep looking in the wrong area to debug the issue -

I would do something like -

```
var foo = ko.observableArray();
datacontext.getFoo(foo, someId)
     .then(doSomethingElse)
     .fail(youFail);
```

and in my data context I would return something from local storage

```
  var getFoo = function (fooObservable, id) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('Foozballs')
            .where('id', '==', id)
            .orderBy('id');

        return manager.executeQueryLocally(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
  }
```

and would continually get back error(s) stating that

```
Object [Object array] has no method 'then'
```

See below answer for what I think caused it and if anyone else wants to improve the answer that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer mentioned, executeQueryLocally is synchronous and returns immediately. If you want to query the cache but still make it "look" async, the simplest way is the use the executeQuery method with  ***FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache***. i.e change your code to

```
var getFoo = function (fooObservable, id) {
    var query = EntityQuery.from('Foozballs')
        .where('id', '==', id)
        .orderBy('id')
        .using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
}
```

Note that this uses executeQuery instead of executeQueryLocally.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration Jay.  I struggled with this for quite some time and saw no answers on here about the specific error, which is why I posted question / answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that executeQueryLocally is done synchronously since it is from local storage and therefore you cannot use 'then' for when it completes.  The proper method to resolve the callback is to execute the query locally and then return

```
return Q.resolve();
```

to return a callback at completion of the query.